# Is there an Aspose way of getting text, including the line breaks/carriage return, out of a cell in Excel?

Tags: .net, excel, aspose-cells

I have and Excel sheet that has data with line breaks in cells. So, for example, the text

```
The quick brown fox

jumped over the lazy dog
```

would show up in one cell - let's say "A1" for simplicity's sake.

I am pulling this into a `string` variable using Aspose with the following code

```
var book = new Workbook("MyPath.xls");
var cells = book.Worksheets[0].Cells;
object value1 = cells["A1"].Value;
string value2 = cells["A1"].StringValue;
```

This is not getting the line breaks so `value1` and `value2` look like `The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog`.

**Is there an Aspose way of getting text, including the line breaks/carriage return, out of a cell in Excel?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the latest release of Aspose.Cells. It includes the carriage returns and line breaks.
If you are displaying the string value in a browser, then all line breaks will be ignored unless you wrap in pre tag.

You can do the following to verify it.

1. Check the value of the String variable in Visual Studio debugger.
   [image: Visual Studio Debugger]
2. Write the String value to a text file and view it's contents in any Notepad or any editor. It should include the line breaks.

   File.WriteAllText(@"D:\Data\Aspose\Forums\data\a1.txt", a1);

[image: Notepad view of text with line breaks]

And here is the screenshot of the Excel file that I used.

[image: Excel file]

I work for Aspose as a Developer Evangelist.